# PowerShell - Allow non-admin users to disable/enable Tasks

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, script

I have a task that triggers every hour, and runs a powershell script. I am supposed to deploy this script along with the task on workstations, where all users are non-admin users, however, the users need to be able to Enable/Disable this script manually.

Using "**Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "task_name"**" in a separate script (START.ps1) obviously doesn't work without admin privileges. Is there any workarounds that will allow these non-admin users to enable/disable the task?

I've already tried to create the task with a non-admin user, but they still were not able to use the Enable-ScheduledTask/Disable-ScheduledTask cmdlets.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should be able the create a batch file that runs the Task Scheduler and then in the Task properties to use Elevated User and authorize that. Two step process - run the scheduler which then runs the task. See if that works.

Comment: @John Okay, just to clarify...Create a batch file that runs the taskschd.msc application, and in the same batch file, enable the task?

Comment: Maybe create a batch file that sets the trigger to run the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing this from memory.. but..

1. Give the user account (who will be running this) permissions to `C:\Windows\System32\tasks`.  This is where the actual tasks are written so the user will need to be able to read/write/change there.  READ SECURITY NOTE AT THE BOTTOM.
2. Add that user account via the group policy editor (or domain group policy) to:  `Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings ->  Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Log on as a batch job`

Notes:

- You will find that with folders like the tasks folder, the explorer will not let you browse (even though *you* might be an admin and have the rights to do so).  I myself use [QDir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir/History)  **as an admin** to poke around where explorer.exe won't allow me to see *and* the problem is ***not based on permissions***.
- Without some real creativity, ***you will potentially open up Pandora's box by granting these rights to ordinary users***.  It is possible that you can add only `BROWSE/READ` to the tasks folder for your user, pre-create the task for them, then add the `CHANGE` permission for your user to the task file itself.  This would be safer, will probably work but I haven't tried it.  You be the guinea pig ;)
- Consider using Users or better still Domain users as the account if you want to simplify all of this via automation.

Good luck!